# Why does autoconf escape defines?

Tags: autoconf

Is this a typical behavior in autoconf that quotes in autotools generated defines are escaped?

Ie instead of

> -DFOO="foo\ bar"

it produces

> -DFOO=\"foo\ bar\"

The escaped version works fine in newer gcc but for gcc 4.5.1 it fails. Unfortunately I can not use newer gcc on this platform so I need to somehow find a way to prevent autoconf from escaping the quotes. Does anyone know how?

Comment: can you show us the code that generates these defines?

Comment: It is generated for things like package version by autoconf. I don't know exactly where. If I did I would have fixed it.